# Segmenting x-axis of a line chart in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

So ive been looking to see if its possible in highcharts to do the following:
[image: chart]

on the x-axis it isnt showing the actual x-axis values it is custom labels that segment the chart into 3 sections.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation will be very easy with Highcharts. You can just use two x-axes, hide the first one and adapt the second one for your needs. For example:

```
xAxis: [{
    visible: false
}, {
    lineWidth: 2,
    min: -0.5,
    max: 2.5,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    categories: ['30 Days Before', 'Insight Period', '30 Days After']
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/12zbg0m3/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis